# how to check sqlite column contain null object reference?

Tags: sqlite, nullpointerexception

I want to check the sqlite db column index having null value.
I have paste below code,

```
int index2=cursor.getColumnIndex(DataHelper.INTIME);
String datein=cursor.getString(index2);
System.out.println(datein);
```

output is:null.  but the blow code was giving me error. help me to solve this issue

```
int index2=cursor.getColumnIndex(DataHelper.INTIME);
String datein=cursor.getString(index2);
if(datein.equals("null"))
        {
        System.out.println(datein);
        }
```

and also I tried blow code but no help, where am I doing mistake

```
boolean bb=cursor.getString(index2).isEmpty();
        if(bb)
        {
            System.out.println("null");
        }
```

when I write above code, I am getting following error message. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference. pls help me solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL NULL values and Java `null` values are not necessarily the same.

If you want to check for NULL values, call [isNull()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/AbstractCursor.html#isNull%28int%29) before trying to read a string.

Comment: Thanks you have solved my issue. I am checking cursor.isNull(index); its working fine.